# How to change the DataTemplate of a custom type based on a ViewModel property?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'd like to be able to change the `DataTemplate` that my custom class is using, based on a property in the `ViewModel`.

I can't find any clear examples and I feel like I might not know enough about `WPF` or `XAML` to know if this is even possible.

My `ViewModel` property represents whether the user has collapsed a column on one side of the application. If the column is collapsed, I want to only show the Image for each user, and if the column is expanded, I'll show the picture, first name and last name in a `StackPanel`.

I feel like there is something really basic that I just don't understand yet and I guess I'm looking for someone who maybe tried something like this or knows how to do this the right way.

## User.cs

```cs
public class User
{
  public string ImageFile {get; set;}
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
  public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

I'm using an `ObservableCollection<User>` to hold my collection of `User` objects in the viewmodel.
My 2 DataTemplates that I'd like to use. (right now I'm just using a default image and text to see how it looks)

## DataTemplates

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserCollapsed">
  <Image Source="/Images/anon.png" 
         Height="50" 
         Width="50"
         Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="UserExpanded">
  <StackPanel>
    <Image Source="/Images/anon.png" 
           Height="50" 
           Width="50"
           Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
     <TextBlock Text="Firstname"/>
     <TextBlock Text="Lastnamehere"/>
   </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
```

I've tried to write a style, and apply that to my ItemsControl in the view, and I've tried writing a datatemplate that uses triggers to decide which template to use, but I can't quite figure out where I'm going wrong.

## Style

```xml
<Style x:Key="userTemplateStyle" TargetType="ItemsControl">
  <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource UserExpanded}"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ColumnIsCollapsed, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource UserCollapsed}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I get the following exception when I add the Style property on my ItemsControl in XAML.

## Exception

```cs
{"Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Windows.DataTemplate'."}
```

And the DataTemplate that I tried to use as the ItemTemplate of the ItemsControl. (I feel like this is the wrong way to go about it but I tried anyway)

## DataTemplate

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type md:CUser}">
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ColumnIsCollapsed, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="DataTemplate" Value="{StaticResource UserCollapsed}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

## ItemsControl

```xml
<ItemsControl Visibility="{Binding ColumnVisibility}"
  Style="{StaticResource userTemplateStyle}"
  BorderThickness="0"
  Name="itcLoggedInUsers"
  Margin="0"
  ItemsSource="{Binding LoggedInUsers}"
  Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Comment: Read up on DataTemplateSelector, here's a good example http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

Comment: @Phil Yeah if you have an example that is specific to my needs, a property in the *ViewModel* not the model itself, then by all means, link away. http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector Is what I went thru trying to figure out if a DataTemplateSelector is what I needed and found out that it does not work in my case AFAIK.

Comment: The example in your link gives you all the info you need . Look at his custom datatemplateselector class, he is accepting an item object and casting to string. If you aren't using strings, cast to your appropriate object, which would be your view model. Then write your logic comparing the property on the viewmodel and return the appropriate datatemplate

Comment: @failedprogramming The object he is accepting is the object in the list of strings. The object my DataTemplateSelector would receive, is of type User, because I have a collection of User objects set as the data source for my itemscontrol. The user object does not have the viewmodel property ColumnIsCollapsed, that is located in the viewmodel for my window that the itemscontrol is in.

Comment: I see, sorry I didn't realize the target property was on the window view model. What I do to solve this is, when I create the User class, I pass a reference of the window view model to the User class using constructor injection. Your User class would now have access to the window view model properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I over thought this problem. If I needed to show or hide an element in the `DataTemplate` based on a `boolean` property of the `ViewModel`, I could just bind the visibility of the element to the property on the `ViewModel`, and use a converter to return a Visibility.

## Solution

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type md:User}">
  <StackPanel>
    <Image Source="/Images/anon.png" 
           Height="50" 
           Width="50"
           Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Firstname" Visibility="{Binding ColumnIsCollapsed, Source={StaticResource ViewModel},Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolVisibility}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Lastnamehere" Visibility="{Binding ColumnIsCollapsed, Source={StaticResource ViewModel},Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolVisibility}}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

## Converter

```cs
public class InvertBoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    var theBool = (bool)value;
    if (theBool)
      return Visibility.Collapsed;
    else
      return Visibility.Visible;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WpfApplication8="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350">
<Window.Resources>
    <WpfApplication8:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="UserCollapsed" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="UserExpanded">
        <StackPanel Width="200"
                    Height="200"
                    Background="Red">
            <TextBlock Text="Firstname" />
            <TextBlock Text="Lastnamehere" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="userTemplateStyle" TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource UserExpanded}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ColumnIsCollapsed, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource UserCollapsed}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="grid" DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
    <ItemsControl Name="itcLoggedInUsers"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Margin="0"
                  BorderThickness="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding LoggedInUsers}"
                  Style="{StaticResource userTemplateStyle}" />

</Grid>
```

And the ViewModel

```
  public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _columnIsCollapsed;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ColumnIsCollapsed = false;
        LoggedInUsers = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        LoggedInUsers.Add(new User(){FirstName = "SSSSSS", LastName = "XXXXXX"});
    }
    public bool ColumnIsCollapsed
    {
        get { return _columnIsCollapsed; }
        set
        {
            _columnIsCollapsed = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ColumnIsCollapsed"));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> LoggedInUsers { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string ImageFile { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```